# C++ Object Constructor with Temporary Object as Argument

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, object-initializers, temporary-objects

I've written some code and it suddenly occurred to me that what I'm doing might be a really bad idea. Here is a sort of abstract example. The key point is the passing by reference of the vector.

```
// vector.hpp
class vector {
    vector(double x, double y, double z);
}

// particle.hpp
class particle {
    particle(const vector& _init_position);
    vector m_position;
}
```

So I have written some code to represent a `class vector`, which contains 3D vector stuff, and have also written a particle class, the position vector of which can be initialized with the constructor and a vector instance.

In my `main()` function, I was using a temporary object to initialize particle objects, like so:

```
int main() {

    particle my_particle(vector(0.0, 1.0, 2.0)); // Temp vector instance - problem?
}
```

Here you can see that a temporary vector instance is created, I assume it is placed on the stack somewhere, and then the constructor of particle is called.

Is this okay or is it an example of very bad code? I suspect the latter, as since I am passing by reference, and therefore the instance of the temp vector might not be valid?

Hopefully someone can clarify this?

Comment: You should, read up on rval references

Comment: It is perfectly OK. Happens all the time. For example, whenever you pass `"Hello"` to a function taking `const std::string&`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Argh, should have thought of that example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are permitted to pass a temporary object to a function as either a value or const reference parameter. It is a good thing, as you can save copies when passing by const reference.

Comment: Why does it have to be a const reference? I notice it will not compile without the const.

Comment: @EdwardBird There is no technical reason why not (as Visual Studio supports it as an extension), it's just not allowed. I believe they thought it would encourage bad coding practices.

Comment: Well that's fair enough I suppose. Everything must be const and all that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the implementation of the vector constructor, but the member is a value, so I assume the constructor is copying its argument to the member. If that's the case then passing a const ref is exactly what you want to do to avoid unnecessary copies.

What you don't want to do is hold on to a reference to (or address of) that argument.